# JqGrid Context menu and sub menus

Tags: jqgrid, contextmenu, submenu

I am using Jqgrid 4.5.4 version. To achieve right click context menu functionality I am using Jquery Plugin for right click context menus (http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/).

My requirement is to show the sub menu inside main right click context menu. For example:

```
--------------------------
Delete
Add
Highlight > ---------------
             Highlight doc1
             Highlight doc 2
           ----------------
Edit
----------------------------
```

When I click on "Highlight" context menu option, sub menu opens up with "Highlight doc 1" and "Highlight doc 2". I could not achieve the same functionality with context menu plugin.

Could anyone please provide some solution.

Here is my code:

```
loadComplete : function(data) {
$("tr.jqgrow", this)
    .contextMenu('rightClickMenu', {
        bindings : createContextMenuBindings(),
        onContextMenu : function(event) {
           var rowId = $(event.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id");
               return createContextMenu(myMap[rowId].ctxMenu);
        }
    });
}

function createContextMenuBindings() {
var bindings = {
    'delete' : function(trigger) {
        handleDelete(trigger.id);
    },
    'add' : function(trigger) {
        handleAccept(codeType, trigger.id, true);
    },
    'highlight' : function(trigger) {
               // This case I have to show sub menu with different options
    }
    };
return bindings;
}

function createContextMenu(ctxMenu) {
var menuItem = '';

if (ctxMenu != null) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < ctxMenu.length; i++) {
        if (ctxMenu[i].display) {

            var subMenu = ctxMenu[i].subCtxMenu;

            if(subMenu != null && subMenu.length > 0) 
            {
                 menuItem += "<li class='menuitem dropdown' id= "+ ctxMenu[i].handler + ">";
                 var ulTag = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-link" data-toggle="dropdown">' + ctxMenu[i].name +
                             '<span class="caret"></span>'+
                             '</a>';
                 ulTag += "<ul class='subrowul dropdown-menu'>";  
                 $.each(subMenu, function( index, value ) {
                     ulTag += "<li class='submenuitem' id= '"+ value.handler + "'>" + value.name + "</li>";
                });
                 ulTag += "</ul>";
                 menuItem += ulTag;
             }  
             else 
             {
                 menuItem += "<li class='menuitem' id= "+ ctxMenu[i].handler + ">" + ctxMenu[i].name; 
             }
             menuItem += "</li>";

        } 
$('#rightClickMenu > ul li.menuitem').remove();
$("#rightClickMenu > ul").append(menuItem);
if (menuItem == '') {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}
```

I would appreciate your answers. 
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I am answering to my own question. I could able to integrate Jquery context menu to jqgrid. Now I could able to see menu and sub menus. I am attaching some code for anybody looking for the answer:

Below logic will be called after jqgrid load complete by row.

```
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: 'tr#'+rowId,
        build: function($trigger, e){
            // ctxMenu is rendered from server.
            var ctxMenu = jqGridJsonResponseMap[code_type]    [$trigger[0].id].rowInfo.ctxMenu;
            // ctx menu options constructed for each row. It is dynamic based on each row.  
            var _items = getCtxMenuOptionsByRowId(ctxMenu, code_type, $trigger[0].id);
            return {
                callback: function(key, options) {
                    // each context menu has differnt callback
                    ctx_bindings[key](key, options, code_type);
                },
                items: _items
            };
        }
    });
```

Comment: I didn't find any solution yet. However I found standalone context menu Jquery plugin, which supports sub menu. [link](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html). I don't know anybody has tried to integrate this with Jqgrid. I would apperciate your comments.

Comment: I found the solution and updated the query with answer. Let me know if anybody looking for more details.